# Unable to call PHP webservice in phone gap application

Tags: php, android, html, web-services, cordova

Hi I am new to phone gap.
I am developing an application in which I am calling JSON webservice created in PHP as follow,

/*-------------calling web service-----------*/

```
jsonp("http://hostName/hotel/fileName.php?callback=jsondata");
```

when I run HTML 5 application on browser webservices are called properly but when I create phone gap application for android and run it on device webservices are not called and I am not receiving data.

Can any one please tell me what to do?

Comment: Post your whole code, then we might be able to help you. Right now its very unclear.

Comment: you can check the access origin parameter in config.xml

Comment: @  QuickFix: It is set to "*"

Comment: @riskPlayGround This is how I am processing                                  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">"use strict";
    function jsonp(url)
 {    }

 /*------------callback function defined in webservice(loads when web service is called)-------------*/
    function jsondata(data)
 {// processing webservice response here}
 /*-------------calling web service-----------*/
 jsonp("http://hostname/hotelTab/filename.php?callback=jsondata");

Answer (score 0):

have you provided internet permission in your android.manifest file like this.....`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`